# conditional format excel epplus if (cell.value<0) fill red

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I´m trying to apply conditional format to Excel using EPPLUS so that a range of cells is filled with red color if the value is negative.

I try this code that if the value of the cell is bigger that the value of the next cell, that cell is filled with red

```
    ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("J2:J"+(listaMargenes.Count+2));
   string _statement="IF(OFFSET(J3,0,-1)-J3>0,1,0)";
   var _cond4 = hoja.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
  _cond4.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
  _cond4.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  _cond4.Formula = _statement;
```

this Works fine, but if i change:

```
IF(OFFSET(J3,0,-1)-J3>0,1,0)
```

by this:

```
if(J3<0)
```

does not Works, when opening the Excel says there is corrupted data.

any idea of how to write the correct way tu put in red the cells with negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IF` statement in excel does not allow for an optional `value_if_true` part anymore (I believe in older versions it did): [MS IF Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2)

So change it to something like:

```
string _statement = "if(B3<0, 1)";
```